# How to save svg in pycairo w/o context manager

Tags: python, svg, pycairo

I have a `test.py` script that I use simply this way:

```py
>>> import test
>>>
```

Inside `test.py`:

```py
import cairo


sfc = cairo.SVGSurface("test.svg", 720, 720)
ctx = cairo.Context(sfc)
ctx.set_source_rgb(.5, .5, 1)
ctx.arc(360, 360, 300, 0, 6.28)
ctx.fill()
```

I get no `svg` output until I `Ctrl+D` in the console.

Using a context manager (`with cairo.SVGSurface("test.svg", 720, 720) as sfc:`) produces the `svg` file immediately once module imported. But, in my (larger) project, I declare the surface in a constructor, and drawings are made in a method... so I cannot use the context manager.

How can I "close" the surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/surfaces.html) You call surface.finish() and then surface.flush()

```
import cairo


sfc = cairo.SVGSurface("test.svg", 720, 720)
ctx = cairo.Context(sfc)
ctx.set_source_rgb(.5, .5, 1)
ctx.arc(360, 360, 300, 0, 6.28)
ctx.fill()
sfc.finish()
sfc.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks! Oh! It was a RTFM question... sorry .
`flush()` should be before `finish`, shouldn't be ?

Comment: Per the documentation again... After calling finish() the only valid operations on a Surface are flushing and finishing it